# How do you calculate the minimum velocity for this problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

I need help with the question below. I have started with that the distance travelled in the x - direction has to be greater than 2R and the same goes for in the y - direction. I then used the equations for x = vcos(a)t and y = vsin(a)t-4.91t^2. How can I continue, and is my approach any good?

Thank you!
[image]